# C# searching for string in large text file. If you search the same file goto line you last read and start search

Tags: c#, string, search

If I am searching for strings in the same LOG file many times through the day would it be faster to somehow go to the last line read in the file on the previous search and then begin reading line by line? Would there be any significant savings here?

### EXAMPLE FILE

process ID    logic

11111         Run some silly logic on middle tier servers.

11111         Still running logic

22222         Run some silly logic on middle tier servers from another user.

11111         Oh look the first process is done.

22222         Still running logic on the second process.

There are times I want many lines of a file from the last time I last loaded it. Currently I use UltraEdit to load the file once and then update file but this still takes quite a bit of time.

In this example above I want ever line from the first process.

### NOTE:

1. The file can be several hundred MB in size at times.
2. The example above is abbreviated, each process ID may contain 100''s of lines of logic.
3. I am accessing the log file across a network. I have found that with UE it is faster to load the file from across the network and then continue to update file than to copy to my local PC and then open it.
4. I am hoping to have a C# console application that can be ran from powershell and pipe the lines I want to the screen or to a file.

Another question I have is what would make this process as efficient as possible? 
1. in regards to C# methods used for my file size?
2. in regards to application used to write the utility? I have powershell, C#, C++, perl

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @B8factor, please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible using Stream.Seek.  You would just have to remember what the last position in the stream was, then move forward from there. If your log file only adds lines to it, this will work just fine, and it will certainly be faster than reading and scanning the same lines over and over again.

If you post some of your existing code, I can even help you write the code to do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've wanted to implement something like this myself, so I took some time to give it a shot. Here's an extension method (you'll have to put it in a static class) to `FileStream` I've come up with:

```
public static string ReadLineAndCountPosition(this FileStream fs, ref long position)
{
    //Check if too great a position was passed in:
    if (position > fs.Length)
        return null;
    bool is_carriage_return = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    fs.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    while (position < fs.Length)
    {
        var my_byte = fs.ReadByte();
        position++;
        //Check for newlines
        if (is_carriage_return && my_byte == 10)// \n
            return sb.ToString();
        if (my_byte == 13)                     // \r
            is_carriage_return = true;
        else
        {
            is_carriage_return = false;
            sb.Append((char)my_byte);
        }

    }
    return sb.ToString();//We've consumed the entire file.
}
```

And to use it, you can use `ReadLineAndCountPosition` by simply calling it and passing in a `long` parameter which we will save the position in. We will simply .Seek() to this position some time later.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("testfile.txt",FileMode.Open);
    long saved_position = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        string current_line = fs.ReadLineAndCountPosition(ref saved_position);
        if (current_line == null || current_line == "SomeSearchString")
            break;
    }

    //Some time later we want to search from the saved position:
    while(true)
    {
        string current_line = fs.ReadLineAndCountPosition(ref saved_position);
        if (current_line == null || current_line == "SecondSearchString")
            break;
    }
}
```

I ran a few tests myself, and it seems to have worked fine. Let me know if you have any troubles. Hopefully it helps you out.